# How can I link a jframe to a jbutton using Java

Tags: java

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this is to jButton

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

```
    new Libraryms().setVisible(true);
    this.setVisible(false);
```